# Scss files are not compiled as css file in ionic 5

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic5

I am using **ionic 5** with **angular 8** in my project. I have introduced Sass variables SCSS files which is not getting converted into CSS. I can see only SCSS file compiled while serving with ionic serve command.

What am I doing wrong here? How to compile SCSS into CSS in live reload always. Please suggest a way. Thanks in advance.

```
$secondary-color: #162a38;
$base-color: #407294;

.custom-alert .alert-input {
  color: $base-color !important;
}
```

My package.json look like below:

```
"dependencies": 
"@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
"@ionic-native/base64": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.4.0",
"@ionic/core": "5.4.0",
"@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
"com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
"cordova": "^9.0.0",
"cordova-android": "8.1.0",
"cordova-ios": "5.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"fast-glob": "^3.2.4",
"firebase": "^7.6.1",
"ionicons": "^5.2.3",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"ngx-quill": "^12.0.1",
"npm": "^6.13.4",
"quill": "^1.3.7",
"rxjs": "~6.5.1",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"


"devDependencies": 
"@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
"@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^5.19.0",
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.15.0",
"typescript": "~3.4.3"
```

My angular.json build scripts looks like below:

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "www",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/assets",
            "output": "assets"
          },
          {
            "glob": "**/*.svg",
            "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
            "output": "./svg"
          }
        ],
        "styles": [
          {
            "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
          },
          {
            "input": "src/global.scss"
          }
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
```

Comment: Did you solve this?